# React returns older state value onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am adding a component onclick and keeping track of the components using useState Array. However when I go to remove one of the added components, it doesn't recognize the full component Array size, only the state that was there when that component was initially added.

Is there a way to have the current state recognized within that delete function?

https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-water-jxnup

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const Span = props => {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{props.index}</span>
        <button onClick={() => deleteSpan(props.index)}>DELETE</button>
        Length: {spans.length}
      </div>
    );
  };
  //set initial span w/ useState
  const [spans, setSpans] = useState([<Span key={0} index={Math.random()} />]);
  //add new span
  const addSpan = () => {
    let key = Math.random();
    setSpans([...spans, <Span key={key} index={key} />]);
  };
  //delete span
  const deleteSpan = index => {
    console.log(spans);
    console.log(spans.length);
  };
  //clear all spans
  const clearInputs = () => {
    setSpans([]);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {spans}
      <button onClick={() => addSpan()}>add</button>
      <button onClick={() => clearInputs()}>clear</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should not create component inside the rendering flow, it will mess up React's lifecycle.

Comment: Also, storing React elements (rendered JSX, like `<Span />`) inside the state is a code smell which could cause other bugs down the line.

Comment: Store only the raw data, and re-render according to it with JSX. Pass all the necessary data as props to avoid creating components on the fly, or use simple helper function instead of a component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)

Comment: Couldn't find documentation or a good answer specifically about dynamically created components in a render function, so [I wrote one myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59636503/1218980).

Comment: Thanks Emile, ok I see, i was going down the wrong path w/ it (new to react)... I think that should get me on track! Yea span was just an example, but i see what u mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - **Explaining why you are facing the issue descibed on your question**

When you are adding your new span on your state, it's like it captures an image of the current values around it, including the value of `spans`. That is why logging `spans` on click returns you a different value. It's the value `spans` had when you added your `<Span />` into your state.

This is one of the benefits of [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Every `<Span />` you added, created a different closure, referencing a different version of the `spans` variable.

---

Is there a reason why you are pushing a Component into your state? I would suggest you to keep your state plain and clean. In that way, it's also reusable.

You can, for instance, use `useState` to create an empty array, where you will push data related to your `spans`. For the sake of the example, I will just push a timestamp, but for you might be something else.

```
export default function App() {
  const Span = props => {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{props.index}</span>
        <button onClick={() => setSpans(spans.filter(span => span !== props.span))}>DELETE</button>
        Length: {spans.length}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const [spans, setSpans] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      {spans.length
        ? spans.map((span, index) => (
            <Span key={span} index={index} span={span} />
          ))
        : null}
      <button onClick={() => setSpans([
        ...spans,
        new Date().getTime(),
      ])}>add</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSpans([])}>clear</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I hope this helps you find your way.

Comment: Thanks Michalis, yes this explains exactly where I was going wrong, I didn't realize it was using a closure when creating the new component.